# Reserve a vector of reference_wrapper objects, how it is possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14, reference-wrapper

[`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper) isn't default constructable. So I can't write any of:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vec(10);
std::array<std::reference_wrapper<int>, 3> arr;
```

However, and to my surprise, you can invoke the [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) member function of a vector of `std::reference_wrapper` objects and effectively change its capacity.

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vec;  
vec.reserve(10);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52850b56bb1b1161)

How is this possible since `std::reference_wrapper` has no default constructor?

Comment: `reserve()` doesn't create objects.  What if you did `resize()` instead?

Comment: Almost none of the what you wrote in your question has anything to do with your question...

Comment: @Barry feel free to edit then...

Comment: @Barry or propose improvements...

Comment: @101010 Reduced. Feel free to rollback if you dislike the new reading.

Comment: @Barry No I trust your judgement as I am a fan of yours and I'm convinced of your solid C++ knowledge, but It would be highly appreciated if you could spare some of your valuable time to explain, briefly of course, the reasons why these wordings aren't related. Thanks either way.

Comment: @101010 Sure. Your question is really: why can I `reserve` a `vector<reference_wrapper<T>>`. The first section is about references, but you don't have any references. The second section is explaining what `reference_wrapper` is - but that's also not really relevant since your question would be just as valid for reserving a vector of `struct foo { foo(int ) };`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`reserve` only allocates uninitialized block of memory enough to fit `N` units without causing reallocation when pushing `N` new elements.

`reserve` doesn't build any new elements. Worst case it only moves/copies already created ones.

Comment: Without causing re-allication when adding new N units

Comment: I rephrased the sentence

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to [SGI STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html) implementation

In stl_vector.h:

```
void reserve(size_type __n) {
    if (capacity() < __n) {
      const size_type __old_size = size();
      iterator __tmp = _M_allocate_and_copy(__n, _M_start, _M_finish);
      destroy(_M_start, _M_finish);
      _M_deallocate(_M_start, _M_end_of_storage - _M_start);
      _M_start = __tmp;
      _M_finish = __tmp + __old_size;
      _M_end_of_storage = _M_start + __n;
    }
  }

void resize(size_type __new_size) { resize(__new_size, _Tp()); }
```

reserve doesn't create new element, however resize does.

Comment: Do you have any idea how old the SGI STL is?

Comment: @sleeptightpupper As it's old, it's easy to read, and I believe the basic idea of STL doesn't change much.

Comment: This is only a single (and old) implementation of a specification. I believe a reference to the specification this code implements would be more appropriate (and more generally applicable) here, especially since the odds of OP *using* the implementation you're posting here are low.

Comment: @jaggedSpire This implementation doesn't implement a the C++ `std`: the C++ `std` was based off of this implementation!  While it is not authorative, the fact that it is one of the simplest and easiest to read ways to understand what many `std` types do is a big plus in its column.  There may and will be differences, but ease of reading can trump exact correctness in many cases.

Comment: @Yakk Oh neat! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

`vector::reserve(N)` simply pre-allocates storage capacity for `N` elements. The vector constructor you are using is the "default fill" constructor - it *creates* `N` default-constructor elements and inserts them into the container.

E.g.

```
vector<T> v;
v.reserve(N);
assert(0 == v.size());
assert(N >= v.capacity());
```

vs

```
vector<T> v(N);
assert(N == v.size());
assert(N >= v.capacity());
```

Per 23.3.6.3.p2 [vector.capacity] of the C++17 working draft, `vector::reserve()` only requires that `T` is `MoveInsertable` into `*this`. The constructor in question is specified in 23.3.6.2.p3 [vector.cons], and requires that `T` shall be `DefaultInsertable` into `*this`.

`reference_wrapper<>` is `MoveInsertable` but not `DefaultInsertable` (it cannot be default constructed, as you mentioned). For the exact definitions of these concepts, see 23.2.1.p15 [containers.requirements.general].